# Writing Text Data To File using ofstream from a function

Tags: c++, ofstream

I am beginner in c++. trying to store data from one function to another and I have several classes and functions which are inheretance. Would appreciate if someone can explain to me how to use the write function to store data to a file. Here is my code

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class studentDetails
{
    public:
    string studentName;
    int age;
    char grade;
    int birthYear;

    void getDetails();

};
void studentDetails::getDetails()
{
    cout<<"Enter the correct data in the forms below\n";
    cout<<"Enter the full names of the student\n";
    getline(cin, studentName);
    cout<<"Enter the age of the student\n";
    cin>>age;
    cout<<"Enter the year of birth\n";
    cin>>birthYear;
}
//define function captureStudentDetails()
void captureStudentDetails()
{
    studentDetails inform;//declared object
    ofstream myfile("studentDetails.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    inform.getDetails();
    myfile.write((char *)&inform, sizeof(studentDetails));//NEED HELP!!!!!!!!!
    myfile.close();
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"Welcome to the student database\n";
    captureStudentDetails();
    return (0);

}
```

I know i can use

```
 myfile<<name
```

for every variable but its a lot of process but it's a long process and could anyone help me with these meaning
`outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&creation), sizeof(bankAccount)` and ios::binary
thanks in advance.

Comment: `myfile.write((char *)&inform, sizeof(studentDetails));` writes `inform` as a binary blob of the exact values of the members. It will not be readable as text. Worse, `string studentName;` is a fairly complicated object that cannot be trivially copied. A simple `string` is a pointer to a `char` array that holds the string data and an integer keeping track of the size of the string. When you perform a binary copy of a `string`, you copy the pointer, not what the pointer points at, and the integer.  The pointer is useless to you. You want the data it points at to be copied to the file.

Comment: More often than not, A bunch of `myfile<<name`s is exactly what you want (don't forget to place a separator between the members so you can easily split them up), but you also want to hide it by writing your own operator `<<` and `>>` overloads for the `studentDetails` class so that all you have to do to write a `studentDetails` is `myfile << inform;`. [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/4581301) offers advice on how to write the `<<` and `>>` operators.

Comment: If you need to write the data in binary form, you'll have to write the `string` member the hard way.  `myfile.write(inform.studentName.data(), inform.studentName.size());` to write the actual string data. But you also need to leave information for the reader to know when to stop. You can use the `string`'s null terminator, `myfile.write(inform.studentName.data(), inform.studentName.size() + 1);`, or you can write in the length of the string before the string itself s the reader knows how many bytes to read.

Comment: Is using the non-member function `void captureStudentDetails()` an assignment requirement? Generally you would want all functions related to your class to be member functions of your class. It is "legal" to do it the way you have it, but it is "awkward" as well.

Comment: Search Keyword: Serialization. [Handy link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

Comment: [Documentation for `ios::binary`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).

Comment: Future note: C++ does not specify the size of `int` and `char`, `int` is at least 16 bits and no larger than the `long` type (and `long` is no longer than `long long`, which currently has no upper limit), so you generally do not want to write them to a file unless you have firm guarantees that all readers you need to support have the exact same size. Even more fun, different computers store integers differently. The most common change is the byte order, or [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). A good file protocol will specify the exact size of each member and byte order.

Comment: Side note: `ofstream` implies an output stream. you can leave out the `ios::out|` in `ofstream myfile("studentDetails.txt", ios::out|ios::app);`

Comment: for serialization you best use a library. To get started you can overload `<<` See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/4117728

Comment: FYI, the statement `studentDetails inform;` creates a **local** variable, that will disappear after execution leaves the function.  Is this your intention?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the captureStudentDetails() is not a must, what am trying to do is write data to a file as text and then add other function to display the students from the text file

Comment: @user4581301 thanks a lot  I've corrected the string variable part right now am using char variable_array and it seems to store the names of the student with no issues to the text files however i would like to place a delimiter to seperate the students data for each student

Comment: Have you used any containers yet like [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? That provides a much more efficient way to hold all student information in memory. That way you read the input file into memory. Add/remove as many students as needed and then write a new data file out when your program closes. You are just using the data file for storage currently (nothing wrong with it, just a lot of reading/writing). You must figure out how you will write the file either way. Why not just write comma-separated values? (e.g. `name,age,grade,birthyear`?)

Comment: Also, bookmark [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page) -- that is "the" C++ reference on the net. Just start learning where the pieces of the language you are dealing with live on the site. It will be a bit cryptic at first, but it provides concise information on how to use each feature in C++, detailing the differences and new features provided by each new revision of the C++ language standard. (it also provides concise examples for how to correctly use a majority of the language features)

Comment: @user4581301 from the operator overloading, I've gathered it's how to use alter the function of an operator for your own user-defined data type. In my case the bit wise operator less but i'm having problems undertanding a bit of the information from geeks https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-in-c/ what's the use of 
Complex operator+(Complex const& obj)  need help in understanding the const(address for obj)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin never used std::vector before but thanks will look into it. Really Appreciate. thanks again.

Comment: Be *very* cautious about using anything from geeks. Much of it is just plain wrong or demonstrates 20 year old coding practices that are discouraged in new code. Using your datafile for storage presents challenges if you ever want to delete a student. If you hold all students in memory, it's trivial. If you are using the file for storage, then to delete a student, you will need to read the students you are keeping from your datafile and write them to a new temporary file. Then close both files are remove the datafile and rename the temp file as the new dtafile.

Comment: Also is your `grade` supposed to be `'A'`, `'B'`, '`C'`..... or are you using `char` for the small integer values of grades `1 - 12`? If you want a signed integer value, just use `int`. If you actually want an ASCII character, the `char` is fine, but that is unclear from your question. Sample input would be helpful. Why are you not prompting for `grade` in `getDetails()`?

Comment: @alson Regarding `Complex operator+(Complex const& obj)`, the + operator never changes either of the operands. 5+2 does not change the value of 5 or 2, instead it returns a new value 7. `const` says even though a reference to an object has been provided, the function is not allowed to use that reference to change the value of `obj`. The function itself should be `const`, `Complex operator+(Complex const& obj) const`, so that it cannot change the either of the operators.

Comment: But the preferred approach is to use a free function: `Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs)` that uses the += operator to do the dirty work. See the **Binary Arithmetic Operators** section of the [Basic Rules link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/4581301) for details.

Comment: And I reiterate the comment about using caution with Geeks for Geeks. Some days it feels like half the job of Stack Overflow is cleaning up after messes Geeks makes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still stuck on the problem, here are a few thoughts that may get you going. While there are still a few points that are unclear from your question, (e.g. whether `grade` is `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, ... or `1`-`12`, and whether your attempt to use `write` is a requirement), but you are making things unnecessarily difficult by choosing `write` and attempting to write the information out in a binary format. While there are many -- many ways you can choose to read and write data to a file, for simple data like `name`, `age`, `birthyear` and `grade`, simply writing as text as comma separated values makes things much easier.

*Don't Hardcode Filenames*

A new programmer mistake that many, if not all make, is to hardcode the filename inside a function. It may be convenient for a quick-test, never hardcode filenames in your actual finished code. While it is perfectly okay to provide a *default* filename to use if the user doesn't provide a filename, the user should not have to modify your source-code and recompile your program just to read and write to another filename.

Instead, take the filename as a program argument or prompt the user for the filename. Taking the filename as a command-line argument is easy to do, as is creating a constant for your default `"studentDetails.txt"`. To provide a default, simply `#define` the filename or create a constant expression. For example, using a simple `#define`, you can do:

```cpp
/* don't hardcode filenames in functions
 * if you need a constant, either #define one
 * or use a constant expression
 */
#define STUDENT_FILE "studentDetails.txt"
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  /* use 1st program argument as filename (STUDENT_FILE if none provided) */
  std::string datafile = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : STUDENT_FILE;
```

(**note:** the subtle distinction between using a `#define` (macro) or constant expression is that a `#define` is a simple compile-time substitution that takes no program storage -- but -- cannot have it's address taken at runtime. If an address is needed, use a constant expression)

**Getting the User-Input and Writing the CSV File**

Since you are only holding one student's data in your program at a time, you will need to take the user input and then write the data to your datafile. As discussed in the comments, using a file as storage has a number of limitations, not the least of which is if you ever need to remove a student's data or checking if the student entered by the user already exists in your file.

You would normally want to read and hold all student data in memory so you could check for duplicates, add students, remove them and then write a new datafile when your program ends. However, since using the file is part of your assignment you will simply need to code around those limitations, which may include creating a temporary and deleting the original datafile and then renaming the temp file  as your datafile if you need to remove students and reading the entire current file to check for duplicates before each addition is made. (those steps are left to you)

To aid with writing your data out to file, overloading the `<<` operator allows you to write your student data simply using `file << student;`. See  [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) under the **Stream extraction and insertion** heading. When using a `class` you can make the overload a `friend` of the `class` to provide access to *private* data members.

Taking that into consideration, your `studentDetails` class could look like the following for the `getDetails()` and write of the information to your datafile:

```cpp
class studentDetails
{
 private:
  std::string name;
  int age, 
      birthyear;
  char grade;
  
 public:
  studentDetails() { name = "", age = birthyear = grade = 0; }
  
  bool getDetails();    /* prompt user to enter student data */
  
  /* declaration for overload of << to write csv student data to stream */
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const studentDetails& s);
};
```

When defining the friend-overload of `<<` outside of the class, you drop the `friend` from the beginning, e.g.

```cpp
/* friend function definition of operator<< overload
 * (you drop friend when defining the friend function outside of the class)
 */
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const studentDetails& s)
{
  /* valdate data is complete before output */
  if (s.name.length() && s.age && s.birthyear && s.grade) {
    os << s.name << ',' << s.age << ',' << s.birthyear << ',' << s.grade << '\n';
  }
  else {  /* show error */
    std::cerr << "(studentDetails not set)\n";
  }
  
  return os;    /* return stream state */
}
```

(**note:** since this is an *output* overload, the class-reference parameter (`studentDetails& s`) is `const` qualified -- it will not change)

**Taking Input From the User**

There is nothing sexy about taking user-input, you just take it piece-by-piece and ensure you ***validate*** every input and every conversion. Note also, that you generally do NOT want to use use a `void` type for an input function return-type. You want a return-type that can indicate whether the input *succeeded* or *failed*. `bool` is fine, as is a simple `int` (`1/0`) to indicate whether all inputs succeeded or failed. With that as a consideration, you can define your `getDetails()` function something like:

```cpp
/* member function definition for getDetails()
 * prompts user to enter student data, returns true if 
 * complete data entered, false otherwise, allows user to
 * simply press Enter at the name prompt to end data entry.
 */
bool studentDetails::getDetails()
{
  /* provide instruction, prompt for name */
  std::cout <<  "\nEnter the correct data in the forms below\n"
                "(Enter alone for name to quit)\n\n"
                "  Full name of student : "; 
  
  if (!getline (std::cin, name)) {  /* read/validate name */
    /* handle manual EOF or stream state error */
    std::cerr << "error: manual EOF or stream error reading name.\n";
    return false;
  }
  if (!name.length()) {   /* check if name empty - done with input */
    return false;
  }
  
  /* prompt for age */
  std::cout <<  "  Age of student       : ";
  
  if (!(std::cin >> age)) {   /* read/validate integer input */
    /* handle error */
    std::cerr << "error: invalid integer value.\n";
    /* empty input stream of characters left by failed int read */
    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return false;
  }
  
  /* prompt for birthyear */
  std::cout <<  "  Year of birth        : ";
  
  if (!(std::cin >> birthyear)) { /* read/validate integer input */
    /* handle error */
    std::cerr << "error: invalid integer value.\n";
    /* empty input stream of characters left by failed int read */
    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return false;
  }
  
  /* prompt for grade */
  std::cout <<  "  Grade                : ";
  
  if (!(std::cin >> grade)) { /* read char, ignoring whitespace */
    /* handle manual EOF or stream state error */
    std::cerr << "error: manual EOF or stream error reading name.\n";
    return false;
  }
  
  /* empty input stream of any characters remaining in line */
  std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  
  return true;
}
```

(**note:** the user will indicate they are done with input simply by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone at the `name` prompt -- which creates a `name` of length `0` used to indicate the user is done with input -- you can use whatever method you like)

Make sure you understand why [std::basic_istream::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is used and how to use it.

That's all that is needed from you class to be able to prompt the user for input, validate the input, and write the input to your datafile. You can write a short `main()` to accomplish the rest, e.g.

```cpp
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  /* use 1st program argument as filename (STUDENT_FILE if none provided) */
  std::string datafile = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : STUDENT_FILE;
  studentDetails student {};    /* instance of studentDetails class */
  
  /* open output stream in append mode for storing data */
  std::fstream f (datafile, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
  
  if (!f.is_open()) { /* validate file is open for writing */
    std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << datafile << "'.\n";
    return false;
  }
  
  while (student.getDetails()) {  /* loop collecting student data */
    f << student;                 /* write in csv format to file */
  }
  
  f.close();      /* close output file - done collecting data */
}
```

Note, while you can simply allow the file to be closed when your program exits, since your next step will be to open the file again in input mode, the file was explicitly closed to allow the reuse of `f.open (...)` for reading your data back in. You may want separate stream instances (e.g. `f_out` and `f_in`) since you will need some way to check if the student entered by the user already exists in your file before writing it to the file. (another significant limitation of not holding all students in memory) Once you write your function to read the csv values back in, you can loop over each student and compare the values to what the user enters *before* you write the new data to the end of the data file.

**Example Use/Resulting Data File**

Adding the needed headers and then compiling and running the file you can confirm the behavior (full-source included below for your reference). For example with the program compiled to `student-file-build` and writing to a new filename of `studentdetails.txt`, you would do:

```
$ ./student-file-build studentdetails.txt

Enter the correct data in the forms below
(Enter alone for name to quit)

  Full name of student : Mickey Mouse
  Age of student       : 95
  Year of birth        : 1928
  Grade                : D

Enter the correct data in the forms below
(Enter alone for name to quit)

  Full name of student : Minnie Mouse
  Age of student       : 95
  Year of birth        : 1928
  Grade                : A

Enter the correct data in the forms below
(Enter alone for name to quit)

  Full name of student : Pluto (the dog)
  Age of student       : 92
  Year of birth        : 1931
  Grade                : F

Enter the correct data in the forms below
(Enter alone for name to quit)

  Full name of student :
```

Checking the resulting datafile, you have:

```
$ cat studentdetails.txt
Mickey Mouse,95,1928,D
Minnie Mouse,95,1928,A
Pluto (the dog),92,1931,F
```

The data is all there in csv format which you can easily read back in with another `friend` function overload of the `>>` operator. It's class declaration would look like: `friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, studentDetails& s);`

**The Complete Source**

The complete source for the user-input and write to the datafile discussed above should look similar to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>   /* for std::numeric_limits */

#include <string>

/* don't hardcode filenames in functions
 * if you need a constant, either #define one
 * or use a constant expression
 */
#define STUDENT_FILE "studentDetails.txt"


class studentDetails
{
 private:
  std::string name;
  int age, 
      birthyear;
  char grade;
  
 public:
  studentDetails() { name = "", age = birthyear = grade = 0; }
  
  bool getDetails();    /* prompt user to enter student data */
  
  /* declaration for overload of << to write csv student data to stream */
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const studentDetails& s);
};


/* member function definition for getDetails()
 * prompts user to enter student data, returns true if 
 * complete data entered, false otherwise, allows user to
 * simply press Enter at the name prompt to end data entry.
 */
bool studentDetails::getDetails()
{
  /* provide instruction, prompt for name */
  std::cout <<  "\nEnter the correct data in the forms below\n"
                "(Enter alone for name to quit)\n\n"
                "  Full name of student : "; 
  
  if (!getline (std::cin, name)) {  /* read/validate name */
    /* handle manual EOF or stream state error */
    std::cerr << "error: manual EOF or stream error reading name.\n";
    return false;
  }
  if (!name.length()) {   /* check if name empty - done with input */
    return false;
  }
  
  /* prompt for age */
  std::cout <<  "  Age of student       : ";
  
  if (!(std::cin >> age)) {   /* read/validate integer input */
    /* handle error */
    std::cerr << "error: invalid integer value.\n";
    /* empty input stream of characters left by failed int read */
    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return false;
  }
  
  /* prompt for birthyear */
  std::cout <<  "  Year of birth        : ";
  
  if (!(std::cin >> birthyear)) { /* read/validate integer input */
    /* handle error */
    std::cerr << "error: invalid integer value.\n";
    /* empty input stream of characters left by failed int read */
    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return false;
  }
  
  /* prompt for grade */
  std::cout <<  "  Grade                : ";
  
  if (!(std::cin >> grade)) { /* read char, ignoring whitespace */
    /* handle manual EOF or stream state error */
    std::cerr << "error: manual EOF or stream error reading name.\n";
    return false;
  }
  
  /* empty input stream of any characters remaining in line */
  std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  
  return true;
}


/* friend function definition of operator<< overload
 * (you drop friend when defining the friend function outside of the class)
 */
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const studentDetails& s)
{
  /* valdate data is complete before output */
  if (s.name.length() && s.age && s.birthyear && s.grade) {
    os << s.name << ',' << s.age << ',' << s.birthyear << ',' << s.grade << '\n';
  }
  else {  /* show error */
    std::cerr << "(studentDetails not set)\n";
  }
  
  return os;    /* return stream state */
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  /* use 1st program argument as filename (STUDENT_FILE if none provided) */
  std::string datafile = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : STUDENT_FILE;
  studentDetails student {};    /* instance of studentDetails class */
  
  /* open output stream in append mode for storing data */
  std::fstream f (datafile, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
  
  if (!f.is_open()) { /* validate file is open for writing */
    std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << datafile << "'.\n";
    return false;
  }
  
  while (student.getDetails()) {  /* loop collecting student data */
    f << student;                 /* write in csv format to file */
  }
  
  f.close();      /* close output file - done collecting data */
}
```

Understand, this just scratches the *tip-of-the-iceberg* as far as the thought process and considerations that go into taking user-input. There is much much more you can do to write a robust user-input routine. Look things over and let me know if you have questions. If you get stuck writing the code to read the csv file back into your program, drop a comment and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: thank you for the great and wide content on how to handle file handling. I'll continue to make changes. I really appreciate maybe by tomorrow i would have finished up the different links you've provided for further understanding. The code you provided is perfect and a lot of the functionalities are amazing. Thanks again.

Comment: You are more than welcome. Learning to program is a journey, not a race. Take your time and enjoy the experience. Let me know if you get stuck on something.